# Applying low-level keyboard hooks with Python and SetWindowsHookExA

Tags: python, winapi

So I'm trying to figure out how to register a global keyboard hook using Python.  From what I have read, it seems to be okay to not have the callback in a DLL. If you use WH_KEYBOARD_LL. I can't confirm that for sure but I find it encouraging that I don't get a 1428 error like I do if I try to hook into say `WH_CBT`.

I get a hook handle but nothing shows up when I press buttons on the keyboard as I would expect.

Any idea's on why my callback is not being called?  Or is this even possible?

The relevant code :

```
import time
import string
import ctypes
import functools
import atexit
import pythoncom
from ctypes import windll

hookID = 0

class Keyboard(object):

    KEY_EVENT_DOWN = 0
    KEY_EVENT_UP = 2

    KEY_ENTER = 2
    KEY_SHIFT = 16
    KEY_SPACE = 32

    HOOK_ACTION = 13
    HOOK_KEYBOARD = 13
    HOOK_KEYDOWN = 0x100
    HOOK_KEYUP = 0x101

    class Hook:
        '''Holds general hook information'''
        def __init__(self):
            self.hook = 0
            self.struct = None            

    class HookStruct(ctypes.Structure):
        '''Structure that windows returns for keyboard events'''
        __fields__ = [
            ('keycode', ctypes.c_long),
            ('scancode', ctypes.c_long),
            ('flags', ctypes.c_long),
            ('time', ctypes.c_long),
            ('info', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))
        ]

    def ascii_to_keycode(self, char):
        return windll.user32.VkKeyScanA(ord(char))

    def inject_key_down(self, keycode):
        scancode = windll.user32.MapVirtualKeyA(keycode, 0)
        windll.user32.keybd_event(keycode, scancode, Keyboard.KEY_EVENT_DOWN, 0)

    def inject_key_up(self, keycode):
        scan = windll.user32.MapVirtualKeyA(keycode, 0)
        windll.user32.keybd_event(keycode, scan, Keyboard.KEY_EVENT_UP, 0)

    def inject_key_press(self, keycode, pause=0.05):
        self.inject_key_down(keycode)
        time.sleep(pause)
        self.inject_key_up(keycode)

    def inject_sequence(self, seq, pause=0.05):
        for key in seq:
            if key == ' ':
                self.inject_key_press(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE, pause)
            elif key == '\n':
                self.inject_key_press(Keyboard.KEY_ENTER, pause)
            else:
                if key in string.ascii_uppercase:
                    self.inject_key_down(Keyboard.KEY_SHIFT)
                    self.inject_key_press(self.ascii_to_keycode(key), pause)
                    self.inject_key_up(Keyboard.KEY_SHIFT)
                else:
                    self.inject_key_press(self.ascii_to_keycode(key), pause)

    def _win32_copy_mem(self, dest, src):
        src = ctypes.c_void_p(src)
        windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory(ctypes.addressof(dest), src, ctypes.sizeof(dest))

    def _win32_get_last_error(self):
        return windll.kernel32.GetLastError()

    def _win32_get_module(self, mname):
        return windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(mname)

    def _win32_call_next_hook(self, id, code, wparam, lparam):
        return windll.kernel32.CallNextHookEx(id, code, wparam, lparam)

    def _win32_set_hook(self, id, callback, module, thread):
        callback_decl = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long)
        return windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(id, callback_decl(callback), module, thread)

    def _win32_unhook(self, id):
        return windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(id)

    def keyboard_event(self, data):
        print data.scancode
        return False

    def capture_input(self):

        self.hook = Keyboard.Hook()
        self.hook.struct = Keyboard.HookStruct()

        def low_level_keyboard_proc(code, event_type, kb_data_ptr):
            # win32 spec says return result of CallNextHookEx if code is less than 0
            if code < 0:
                return self._win32_call_next_hook(self.hook.hook, code, event_type, kb_data_ptr)

            if code == Keyboard.HOOK_ACTION:
                # copy data from struct into Python structure
                self._win32_copy_mem(self.hook.struct, kb_data_ptr)

                # only call other handlers if we return false from our handler - allows to stop processing of keys
                if self.keyboard_event(self.hook.struct):
                    return self._win32_call_next_hook(self.hook.hook, code, event_type, kb_data_ptr)

        # register hook 
        try:          
            hookId = self.hook.hook = self._win32_set_hook(Keyboard.HOOK_KEYBOARD, low_level_keyboard_proc, self._win32_get_module(0), 0)
            if self.hook.hook == 0:
                print 'Error - ', self._win32_get_last_error()
            else:
                print 'Hook ID - ', self.hook.hook

        except Exception, error:
            print error

        # unregister hook if python exits
        atexit.register(functools.partial(self._win32_unhook, self.hook.hook))

    def end_capture(self):
        if self.hook.hook:
            return self._win32_unhook(self.hook.hook)


kb = Keyboard()#kb.inject_sequence('This is a test\nand tHis is line 2')
kb.capture_input()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
kb.end_capture()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I couldn't get your class to work, but I found a similar way to accomplish the same goal [in this thread](http://www.hackerthreads.org/Topic-42395).

Here's the adapted code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

KeyboardEvent = namedtuple('KeyboardEvent', ['event_type', 'key_code',
                                             'scan_code', 'alt_pressed',
                                             'time'])

handlers = []

def listen():
    """
    Calls `handlers` for each keyboard event received. This is a blocking call.
    """
    # Adapted from http://www.hackerthreads.org/Topic-42395
    from ctypes import windll, CFUNCTYPE, POINTER, c_int, c_uint, c_void_p, byref
    import win32con, win32api, win32gui, atexit

    event_types = {win32con.WM_KEYDOWN: 'key down',
                   win32con.WM_KEYUP: 'key up',
                   0x104: 'key down', # WM_SYSKEYDOWN, used for Alt key.
                   0x105: 'key up', # WM_SYSKEYUP, used for Alt key.
                  }

    def low_level_handler(nCode, wParam, lParam):
        """
        Processes a low level Windows keyboard event.
        """
        event = KeyboardEvent(event_types[wParam], lParam[0], lParam[1],
                              lParam[2] == 32, lParam[3])
        for handler in handlers:
            handler(event)

        # Be a good neighbor and call the next hook.
        return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)
       
    # Our low level handler signature.
    CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, POINTER(c_void_p))
    # add argtypes for 64-bit Python compatibility (per @BaiJiFeiLong)
    windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (
        c_int,
        c_void_p, 
        c_void_p,
        c_uint
    )
    # Convert the Python handler into C pointer.
    pointer = CMPFUNC(low_level_handler)

    # Hook both key up and key down events for common keys (non-system).
    hook_id = windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(win32con.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, pointer,
                                             win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

    # Register to remove the hook when the interpreter exits. Unfortunately a
    # try/finally block doesn't seem to work here.
    atexit.register(windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, hook_id)

    while True:
        msg = win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        win32gui.TranslateMessage(byref(msg))
        win32gui.DispatchMessage(byref(msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def print_event(e):
        print(e)

    handlers.append(print_event)
    listen()
```

I've made a high-level library to wrap this: [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard).

Comment: Nice, concise, answer

Comment: After many hours of trying a bunch of different approaches, this seems like the perfect way if you need to listen to keyboard at a low level (without having the console focused). Thanks!

Comment: It works great but I get `key_code`s like `240518168740`. I thought it should return values like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So, how do I convert that to actual character/key being pressed?

Comment: Try removing the upper bits: `240518168740 -> 0x38000000A4 & 0xFFFFFFFF = 0xA4`. `A4` looks like an alt key. Is that correct? Usage example: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: A shot in the dark here, but I don't suppose you'd know how to get it working when focus is in certain applications such as Steam?

Comment: Add `from ctypes import c_int, c_void_p, c_uint
windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (c_int, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_uint)` To support **x64** python.

Comment: How would I go about incorporating a hook like this into a GUI application? I'm currently stuck between "Running the `GetMessage` loop as-is blocks tkinter's main loop" and "running the `GetMessage` loop in its own thread breaks the keyboard hook".

Answer (score 5):

The reason that Tim's original code did not work is because the ctypes function pointer to `low_level_keyboard_proc` was garbage collected, so his callback became invalid and was not called.  It just failed silently.

Windows does not retain Python pointers, so we need to separately retain a reference to the exact `callback_decl(callback)` ctypes function pointer parameter that is passed to SetWindowsHookEx.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with Python specifically, but yes, it should be possible for a low-level keyboard or mouse hook. For other hook types, the hook functions must be in a dll.

HOOK_ACTION should be 0, not 13.