# Python get mouse position and listen for keyboard commands

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard

I have written a small function that gets the current position of the mouse cursor and prints it to a command line. However I want to also be able to press a key at any point and it will run a function. However if there is no key press I want it to continue running the function and printing the position of the mouse...

Code for the mouse pos:

```
while True :
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    data = (str(x) + " " + str(y))
    print data
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The code I added for the key press was this:

```
while True :
    if msvcrt.getch() == "h" :
        data = "h"
    else :
        x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        data = (str(x) + " " + str(y))
    print data
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

However the problem with this is that it waits until I press a key to run the get cursor position. It also doesn't register a key press of h when the program is unfocused which is a necessity.

Thanks for any help,

Ryan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying low-level keyboard hooks with Python and SetWindowsHookExA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817531/applying-low-level-keyboard-hooks-with-python-and-setwindowshookexa)

Comment: So, you want `h` to do something any time you press it? How would you be able to type? I guess if that's what you want though, you need to [register a hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @PeterWood Would a hook work if the console was unfocused? And yes when h is pressed I want it to run a function otherwise keep getting the position of the mouse

Answer (score 0):

You should try "[PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI)"

PyAutoGUI can help you control Mouse and Keyboard
Hope this can help you

Comment: The documentation of PyAutoGUI is at https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used the [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) module for sending and listening for key presses and mouse clicks.

To get the mouse position, you would use:

```
from pynput import*
mouse_controller=mouse.Controller()
print mouse_controller.position
```

To send a key press, you would use:

```
from pynput import*
keyboard_controller=keyboard.Controller()
keyboard_controller.type("Something")
```

You can see more on the [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) module by clicking the link.