# Use keyboard without calling pygame.display.set_mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyboard, pygame

Does pygame.display.set_mode have to be used to utilize the keyboard keys? 
Once I added it to my code everything worked - but I do not want to open a pygame window.

Does anyone know how to utilize the keyboard without having to call pygame.display.set_mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `pygame.display.set_mode` to create a window, since it's this very window that recieves the keyboard events from your OS' window manager.

You can run pygame without a window (by setting the environment variable `SDL_VIDEODRIVER` to `"dummy"`), but you can't recieve keyboard events with pygame then.

Maybe you want to look into low-level hooks (e.g. [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817531/applying-low-level-keyboard-hooks-with-python-and-setwindowshookexa) an example for windows).

Comment: Hmm okay, thank you. I'm using pygame.joystick without opening a window, so I was hoping I would be able to add additional functionality with the keyboard (also without opening a window), but I guess that may not be possible with pygame. Thanks!