# How to get mouse up/down/moved and key press events in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mouseevent, keyboard-events, pywin32

I've been working for a while on a Python 2.7 project written for Linux to add Windows support to it. I'm trying to figure out how to get the event for keyboard press and the mouse moving, being pressed, or being released. I installed the win32api and pyHook but I just can't figure how to get it right. Note that I want it to get the event no matter where it is, not just when its pressed in the command prompt for example. Here is how you would do it in linux:

```
def handle_event(self):
    """ This function is called when a xlib event is fired """

    data = reply.data

    while len(data):
        event, data = rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value(data, self._display.display, None, None)

        if event.type == X.MotionNotify:
            if self._mouse_last_x != None:
                mouse_distance=math.sqrt((event.root_x-self._mouse_last_x)**2+(event.root_y-self._mouse_last_y)**2)
                self.send_event(('mouse_moved',mouse_distance))
            self._mouse_last_x,self._mouse_last_y = event.root_x,event.root_y

        if event.type == X.ButtonPress:
            print event.sequence_number,event._data,event._fields
            self.send_event(('button_down',event._data['detail']))

        elif event.type == X.ButtonRelease:
            print event.sequence_number,event._data,event._fields
            self.send_event(('button_up',event._data['detail']))

        elif event.type == X.KeyPress and event.sequence_number == 0:
            key = event.detail
            self.send_event(('keys_pressed',key,1))

def run(self):
    self.disable_keyboard_interrupt()
    root = self._display.screen().root
    ctx = self._display.record_create_context(
                0,
                [record.AllClients],
                [{
                        'core_requests': (0, 0),
                        'core_replies': (0, 0),
                        'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                        'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                        'delivered_events': (0, 0),
                        'device_events': (X.KeyReleaseMask, X.PointerMotionMask),
                        'errors': (0, 0),
                        'client_started': False,
                        'client_died': False,
                }])

    self._display.record_enable_context(ctx, self.handle_event)
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to get it like this for Windows with any library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Win32 API function [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx).

Example on Python: [Applying low-level keyboard hooks with Python and SetWindowsHookExA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817531/applying-low-level-keyboard-hooks-with-python-and-setwindowshookexa)

pyHook is also good package for 32-bit Python (it's a bit outdated and you need some efforts to re-build it for x64 using MinGW). Example: [Detecting Mouse clicks in windows using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165495/detecting-mouse-clicks-in-windows-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

For detecting the left and right mouse buttons being pressed or released, please check my solution using just win32api here:
[Python mouse click detection just with win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165495/detecting-mouse-clicks-in-windows-using-python)

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: My response guided the OP to use win32api, and referenced an applicable answer that was already provided elsewhere in StackOverflow.  That answer provides the needed detail and working code, without duplication of effort in this thread.