# How use Python to simulate keybaord click to control game?

Tags: python, ctypes, pywin32, pyautogui

I'm trying to create a python script to automate a game.

I already tried these libs:

- `pyautogui`
- `pywin32`
- `ctypes` (I imported this code and calling the function `PressKey`, https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/directkeys.py)

My code is like this:

```
from directkeys import PressKey, ReleaseKey, W
import time

print("Script is gonna start in 5 seconds")
time.sleep(5)

PressKey(W)
time.sleep(10)
ReleaseKey(W)
print("Script finished")
```

I tested this script at `notepad`, it's working pretty well, but it's not working in the game at all.

I thought it was because of need to be direct input, but I think `ctypes` is already sending input as `direct input`.

How can I automate the game using python?

Comment: What's the game you're trying to use this script with? Perhaps the game is able to prevent the user from using a bot.

Comment: The game is `Ran Online`, BTW, I'm playing private server just to learn how to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886546/unable-to-receive-keystrokes-from-steam-and-a-few-other-programs
This question might help? Check for admin privileges and make sure both your program and game are on equal grounds for that.

Comment: Oh boy, I didn't try this way, let me try it than I'll let you know the result. thank you so much @J0hn

Comment: @J0hn just to make sure, the way that I simulating keyboard press (`PressKey`) is sending and `Direct Input` type of input, right?

Comment: Your second w in ReleaseKey is lowercase.

Comment: @Lai32290 I believe so, if you're using the library I google searched and found, I think it uses ctypes, which is how I simulated key presses before with python.

EDIT: Another thing you can try is replacing W with the hex value for it.  So like numlock has a hex value of 0x90.  I think that's the type of input those functions want.

Comment: @Evan, sorry about it, it's typo error.

Comment: @J0hn I'm not sure, but I think hex value should not be the issue, because I'm able to type into a `notepad` using my script. it's not working only in the game.

Comment: I'm at work now, I'll try to run the script as admin permission later, it seems the solution to my problem.

Comment: Hey @J0hn! I executed the script as admin and it just working!!!! thank you so much!!!

Comment: @J0hn, can you create a answer with this `run script as admin permission` solution? Than I vote on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to elevate my comment to an answer since I believe it's what you're looking for.

The W is not the proper input for the PressKey and ReleaseKey functions.  They're looking for hex code input.  You can find the proper hex codes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

The W hex code particularly is 0x57.  So replace "W" with "0x57":

```
from directkeys import PressKey, ReleaseKey, W
import time

print("Script is gonna start in 5 seconds")
time.sleep(5)

PressKey(0x57)
time.sleep(10)
ReleaseKey(0x57)
print("Script finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to make sure it was running either the script or the IDE in Administrator mode.
For some reason, games I wrote scripts for like Black Desert Online or CSGO only detect key presses when I am running it in Administrator.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).