# Python Does Not Detect Keystrokes When Some Windows Have Focus

Tags: python, keylogger, pyhook

I am trying to capture keystrokes sent to a MapleStory private server I created in order to train a neural network, but the below code does not detect any key strokes when the game window has focus. If any other window has focus, it works fine.

I already checked [Applying low-level keyboard hooks with Python and SetWindowsHookExA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817531/applying-low-level-keyboard-hooks-with-python-and-setwindowshookexa/16430918)
but it has the same problem.

I was thinking of running the game client in a virtual machine and capture the keystrokes sent to that, but that is a less than optimal solution.

Does anyone know why I cannot detect key strokes in game, and know a way around it?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```