# How can I understand when the mouse is pressing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, mouselistener, pynput

I want to creat a code in python, while the left button mouse is pressing, print Hello until the button released.

```
  while(TheLeftMouseButtonPressing):
     print('Hello')
```

Comment: it really depends on environment and framework, please check this link and see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817531/applying-low-level-keyboard-hooks-with-python-and-setwindowshookexa

Answer (score 1):

Install pynput from pip.
`pip install pynput`

Then you can listen to mouse clicks like this:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    print("Hello")
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```