# Is there any way to make tkinter window dismiss Win + D command?

Tags: python, tkinter, command, window, shortcut

I'm trying to make some application with python tkinter, that must always stay on the top of the screen. I searched a lot of documents, and I finally know how to set tkinter window to stay on the top, but couldn't find the way to stay top even though the user presses Win + D shortcut.

Is there any way to make tkinter window dismiss Win + D command?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a low-level keyboard hook to essentially "absorb" any forbidden keypresses, though it may be a bit overkill. In this example, I've set up a filter for the left and right Windows keys.

This relies on the [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) module, but could likely be rewritten to use `ctypes` exclusively.

For what it's worth, there are caveats:

- this is a fairly heavy-handed approach, and will prevent any/all Windows-key-related shortcuts from working for as long as it's running
- it will perform this filtering OS-wide, **not just in your application**

This code is largely adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430918/8512262), and the original author also provides a [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) module that abstracts away some of this technical kung-fu - *it's probably worth looking into*.

With all that out of the way, the idea here is that you set up an instance of the `KeyFilter` class and target the `KeyFilter.set_hook` method to run in its own thread, and the keys you set up in the `ForbiddenKeys` enum will be filtered out for as long as that thread (or more likely, your app which creates that thread) is running.

There's a boilerplate example in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block so you can try running it directly to see how it works.

```
import atexit
import ctypes
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
from enum import Enum


class ForbiddenKeys(int, Enum):
    """Enumerator of keycodes that will be filtered out"""
    # NOTE: inheriting from int allows for testing of membership once the Enum
    # is cast to a set, e.g.: 'if <val> in set(ForbiddenKeys)'
    # (int class must come before Enum)
    KEY_LWIN = win32con.VK_LWIN  # 0x5B
    KEY_RWIN = win32con.VK_RWIN  # 0x5C
    ...
    # you can add more keys here as needed
    # e.g.: KEY_LCTRL = 0xA2


class KeyFilter:
    """
    Sets up a Windows low-level keyboard hook to filter out "forbidden" keys:
    (keycodes defined in ForbiddenKeys enum)
    """
    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
    CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
        ctypes.c_int,
        ctypes.c_int,
        ctypes.c_int,
        ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)
    )

    def _filter_handler(self, nCode, wParam, lParam) -> int:
        keycode = lParam[0] & 0xFFFF_FFFF  # upper bits of keycode are masked
        if keycode in set(ForbiddenKeys):
            return 1
        else:  # key allowed, move along to the next hook
            return self.user32.CallNextHookEx(
                self.hook_id,
                nCode,
                wParam,
                lParam
            )

    def _unhook(self) -> None:
        """Unhook the keyboard hook and stop the listener loop"""
        self.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(self.hook_id)

    def set_hook(self) -> None:
        """Listen for keyboard events until unhooked at exit"""
        handler_ptr = self.CMPFUNC(self._filter_handler)
        # NOTE: argtypes are required for 64-bit Python compatibility
        self.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (
            ctypes.c_int,
            ctypes.c_void_p,
            ctypes.c_void_p,
            ctypes.c_uint,
        )
        # set up a Windows low-level keyboard hook
        self.hook_id = self.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(
            win32con.WH_KEYBOARD_LL,  # hook type: low-level keyboard input
            handler_ptr,  # point to the handler method
            win32api.GetModuleHandle(None),  # handler is in this module
            0,
        )
        atexit.register(self._unhook)  # release hook at interpreter exit
        # start the message loop
        while (msg := win32gui.GetMessage(0, 0, 0)) > 0:
            win32gui.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
            win32gui.DispatchMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test keyfilter
    from threading import Thread

    keyfilter = KeyFilter()
    keyfilter_thread = Thread(
        target=keyfilter.set_hook,
        name='KeyFilter',
        daemon=True,
    )
    keyfilter_thread.start()
    # press ctrl-c or close the terminal to stop the keyfilter
    while True:
        try:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```